# Is enable_if the most concise way to define a function accepting only rvalues, but of any type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++20, template-meta-programming

I'm referring to this:

```cpp
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>>>
auto f(T&&) {}

int main(){
    int i{};
    f(std::move(i)); // ok
    f(int{1});       // ok
    f(i);            // compile time error, as expected
}
```

Are there any other, shorter ways to accomplish the same?

For a moment I thought something like this could work

```cpp
template<typename T>
auto f(decltype(std::declval<T>())&&) {}
```

but the IDE told me *couldn't infer template argument '`T`'*, and I verified [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction), in the section **Non-deduced contexts**, that *the expression of a `decltype`-specifier* is indeed a non-deduced context.

---

I'm interested also in a [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) solution, if any exists.

Comment: Use concepts: `template <std::rvalue_reference T> auto T(T&&) { }`. Simplified everywhere you can have a typename you can have a concept instead of `enable_if`

Comment: Thanks, probably I should have added C++17 as well. Doing it now, but removing C++23, as given C++20 has concepts, I don't expect C++23 to offer an even shorter syntax.

Comment: C++17? Bummer. I think you already have the solution for c++17. You need concepts to make this nicer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, apparently the solution was more obvious than we thought.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't think `std::rvalue_reference` is a thing. :c

Comment: I'd spell `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>` as `!std::is_reference_v<T>`, and use `requires` if this was C++20. Otherwise there's not much to change. I'm not a fan of the second overload, since it requires you to duplicate the function type.

Comment: By the way, it's better to use the `enable_if` on the return type, that way a user can't accidentally put `int n; f<int, bool>(n)`, which overrides the type check.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow This is doubly wrong. `is_rvalue_reference_v` (which is the actual spelling) is a variable template, not a concept, so you can't use it in this context. But even if you could, `T` doesn't deduce as an rvalue reference in the rvalue case - so that constraint would reject everything (`f(42)` deduces `T=int` not `T=int&&`, which is why OP checked if `T&&` was an rvalue reference type, not `T`).

Comment: @Barry I didn't use `is_rvalue_reference_v` for a reason. The type traits use the form `is_something` with `is_something_t` for the type and `is_something_v` for the value., The corresponding concept is then generally named `something` or `Something`. The concept might not exists (yet?) in this case but if it did I would expect it to require that `T&&` is an rvalue reference and therefore work for the deduced `T`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If `rvalue_reference<T>` existed as a concept, then surely `rvalue_reference<int>` would be false because `int` is not an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HolyBlackCat commented, you can use concepts to simplify the function signature

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
  requires (!std::is_lvalue_reference_v<T>)
auto f(T&&) {}
```

Or detect lvalue or rvalue by checking the validity of a lambda expression that accepts an lvalue reference

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
  requires (!requires (T&& x) { [](auto&){}(std::forward<T>(x)); })
auto f(T&&) {}
```

Comment: This should be the acceptable answer over others, as this is the much less typing c++20 version.

Comment: @UserUsing _"much less typing"_ could perhaps be a reason if it was true. The top `requires` in this answer is 41 chars.  The overload solution iin paolo's answer is 43 chars and the `static_assert` I used in my answer is 47 chars.  So, the span is 41-47. I wouldn't select a solution based on that small difference.

Answer (score 8):

Did you try explicitly deleting the l-value overload?

```
template <typename T>
auto f(T &&) {}

template <typename T>
auto f(T &) = delete;
```

Comment: Since this seems to be preferred over only having one function template and using a `static_assert`, I wonder, how come? I'm a bit surprised :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo If you ask me: it delivers intent clearly and it doesn't require you to deal with type traits (nor to `#include <type_traits>`).

Comment: That's true and I do like ithis solution. I do like the `static_assert` better though since it doesn't require overloading the function and _"use of deleted function `'auto f(T&) [with T = ...]'`"_ doesn't say as much as `static assertion failed ... static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>, "f() requires an r-value");` (if the type trait isn't obvious enough). To me it seems `static_assert` was invented partly to be able to make error messages in situations like this clearer. Oh well, it's a matter of taste I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `static_assert` if you don't need SFINAE:

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T&&) {
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>);
}
```